# Update editmask control when datawindow is updated

Tags: events, powerbuilder, datawindow

- I have an edit mask control called `em_runningchecktotal` on my form.
- I have a datawindow control called `dw_receipt` on the same form, and I have another control on another datawindows called `dw_check` (child name) check total.
- The check total amount is empty.
- The user will enter the check amount total in the "check total" field, and I need to copy that amount to the `em_runningchecktotal`. Then with each addition to the datawindows `dw_receipt` in the "check amount" box, I need to subtract that amount from the `em_runningtotal` amount.

Which events do I use on the `dw_check` datawindow to update the initial value, and which event on the `dw_receipt` datawindow do I used to decrement the amount with each entry into the `dw_receipt`?  I am so new to PowerBuilder and inherited this project so any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although your explanation is not very clear but I am sure, you can achieve this by using below datawindow events:

1) ItemChanged

2) ItemFocusChanged